# Why is the this input "value" property not refreshed?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I am learning React while doing a new project with it.

I want to create an input component with a event that is only triggered if the user exits the input or hit enter. ([here is the link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/input-value-render-mdx99b?file=/src/App.js:299-346))

```
const MyInput = ({ value, onValueChange }) => {
  const [myCurrentTypingValue, setMyCurrentTypingValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => setMyCurrentTypingValue(value), [value]);

  const commitChanges = () => {
    const numericValue = Number(myCurrentTypingValue);
    setMyCurrentTypingValue(numericValue);

    if (value !== numericValue) onValueChange(numericValue);
  };

  const handleOnChange = (e) => setMyCurrentTypingValue(e.target.value);
  const handleOnBlur = () => commitChanges();
  const handleOnKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.charCode === 13) commitChanges();
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="number"
      value={myCurrentTypingValue}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
      onBlur={handleOnBlur}
      onKeyPress={handleOnKeyPress}
    />
  );
};
```

As you can see, when I type something, the input is correctly displayed when I press enter or exit, but when I type a number that starts with 0 (e.g. 000023), although the numerical value is correctly converted, it is still displayed with all zeros in front of it.

[image]

Because I change the state of my component, I expect my input box value property to be refreshed, and it is not:

[image]

Why is this happening? I checked with the debugger tool, my state is correct?

How can I have the input box reflect the new state with the good numeric formatted value?

Comment: Your state is correct but the component was not rerendered.

Comment: `007 === Number(7)` evaluates to true. You may have to convert it to a string to force a state update there. `setMyCurrentTypingValue(numericValue.toString())`;

Comment: Alternatively, you could remove `type="number"` from the `input`.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I don't think the issue is because of component not re-rendering. Component is indeed re-rendering. For some reason, `number` type input is not updating its visual value and it may well be because of `007 === Number(7)` evaluating to true. Changing `value={myCurrentTypingValue}` to `value={myCurrentTypingValue.toString()}` also fixes the issue.

Comment: Ah, that's DOM not updating.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. I will stick to @Yousaf solution {value={myCurrentTypingValue.toString()} which it is the most transcient. Also I prefer to keep type="number" because it filters the user input already somehow. May I ask you to write the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Off-topic: What is your [profile picture](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2020a7f739da6d67e7deb61ed40ba0a6?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG)?

Comment: @jsejcksn it's Zer0 from [Borderlands 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borderlands_2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it's time to "commit" your changes, you should stringify the parsed `number` value and update the input value (which is always a `string`). Here's a self-contained example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGMYAiA8gLJwBmUEIcA5FDvgLQAm1A9LgDbBYB2MWgG4AsAChQkWHADe4uHBZZyyAK5d4aTIxgAaeXBgBPMFjgBhABbI+AcywBRAG78YACRssuWKPrELjUzgCYFQwZBhcSz8AkzMAaSwjACMIZCgWZ1cPPi8fGMM47TwYB28QVwLAswBlLBgamAisAEF8YAg+AtVUR3JyLHxu3sbmvwBfCioaeh1hcXF2djgABXTelDhUGChgOxR0ZDg+VRBk-Lhk1XhgckNLM23d-dDjiE04J2QeFmPT86g934cAYMFUUD4cAADOJyKo+O1OnBwlBegA5f4+OAACieAC4tjs9rYAJQEk5nLFyfxwXCdbbHOAAXjgGMpUFxOxJohpoPBkLZAIAdKE0cg0di+CS4AB+aFwck88YLMTVVmYqAAST4YGuKyoYHQLOpCi+XFUWHJGp5Cl6MAAat8LQSQmEIlEADx1BpNGCtRF8D0UgEAPhDSp5sPhAfV7O1uvg2JkZotui29Ud5qw4wJgp88b1BtQZOK+DKWAqAlkBjpfAZAG0oMgAO6Z1PpmAYFttrAAXWZcB6WFGfuxjWetmxKawJO5KoUQ4c-UGMGx2OlTJDHa7radWDHRLsU73s7T9envbnYhr9PgdJAIGA8BZ6+ZW7tPexKPRGuxTd3WazpGNK1gy1i5N4Vg2PYBJQXYjguAIOR5FAHpuAAKiQAAyBalOUrhbi+WBOBu771Dun7EUKTRQPYMBCtOV43nW8DgXkiRGAAqmABIcak6SZIh7ieN4qEYdhuHlpWMCETixGkdWNIKLcclOEKADWSTMkyLK0A4Ag+LQ0r3o+q5Xgo4zAQofIQjiBgKB6ewJvZCiFKYTIAETBj4HkuQonQAELmlATIyCZT7KkprmdHB9ihWxkHgfYkWudFfAcdx8UiVgGVgClqWfHuoX-j2+UKOwIYGFekVRgiMAdJCLRgGAOIltgJRSa4ikKKB8DnnuaYfnu-YskOI77lCTG8vU-J2VFHosMATiVVFDmWAAjCGeaAk51xwCANjIPY0keuwG0rQVcAettuGyEK93JgNHalZMFV+VdYAMCGHp0koIYyAAUjURBokKTzErcRhJtO4xpicXBcGmABMJLjKdv1YN97CfZjLmnYty1VUqKq9SCOgYBA7wDu1+DECQQq4AwzQU+82JsLgpyuEKdGdQIAVGJqLDYvQlOCCSACEV5M-gLP0QwuQ+NiHpNS1FVXkAA)

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
input[type="number"], pre { font-size: 1rem; padding: 0.5rem; }
```

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.17.10/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

// import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
// import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules instead of the above import statments
const {useEffect, useState} = React;

// Parse a string as a number, but if the string is not a valid number then return 0
function parseNumber (str) {
  const n = Number(str);
  return Number.isNaN(n) ? 0 : n;
}

function NumberInput ({value, setValue}) {
  const [rawValue, setRawValue] = useState(String(value));

  useEffect(() => setRawValue(String(value)), [value]);

  const commit = () => setValue(parseNumber(rawValue));

  const handleChange = (ev) => setRawValue(ev.target.value);

  const handleKeyUp = (ev) => {
    if (ev.key === 'Enter') commit();
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="number"
      onBlur={commit}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onKeyUp={handleKeyUp}
      value={rawValue}
    />
  );
}

function App () {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Number input management</h1>
      <NumberInput {...{value, setValue}} />
      <pre><code>{JSON.stringify({value}, null, 2)}</code></pre>
    </div>
  );
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
reactRoot.render(<App />);

</script>
```